# Stream Camera input over 5G Wifi to multicast address using FFMpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, streaming, webcam

I am trying to stream my Intel RealSense D435 RGB camera input to a multicast address on my network.

*Please note, video streaming, encoding, is very new to me - I do not understand much, when explaining a solution, please give me a few extra details, thanks :)*

**My Hardware Setup:**

- Intel RealSense D435 (with USB Type-C connector)
- Raspberry Pi 4 (4gb Ram) (the server)
- 5G cabable Wifi router (mentioned for full details)

**Firstly, what is the problem:**

When attempting to stream my `/dev/video4` (RBG input) to the network using ([full output](https://pastebin.com/ddyCZZUD)):

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -input_format yuyv422 -video_size 1280x720 -i /dev/video4 -c:v h264_omx -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 1280x720 -r 30 -g 60 -f mpegts udp://238.0.0.1:5000
```

then client side I try viewing the stream with VLC and ffplay.

- VLC

using VLC on a separate network client with network stream `udp://238.0.0.1:5000` loads infinitely with no picture (*I tried streaming to locahost on the pi, and on localhost with `udp://127.0.0.1: 5000` ffmpeg stream did not show either*).

- FFPlay

FFPlay stream was detected on a separate network client, but gives the [this](https://pastebin.com/bthJZdqd) error output when using `ffplay udp://238.0.0.1:5000`.

**Why am I using `h264_omx`?**

Raspberry Pis have a hardware encoding ability, and hoping to take advantage of this, I configured ffmpeg with

```
  --enable-omx \
  --enable-mmal \
  --enable-omx-rpi \
```

[this](https://pastebin.com/ci3KVqRc) (all commands uncommented) is the setup script I used, adapted from [this](https://retroresolution.com/compiling-ffmpeg-from-source-code-all-in-one-script/).

**Was I able to get a picture through the network**

**Yes**, but there were problems. The video was very very choppy and extremely bad quality. To get this, I used the same `ffplay` command as mentioned above on a separate network client and the server command used was with the SW encoder `libx264` ([server full output](https://pastebin.com/fFSB97Ar)) and ([client full output](https://pastebin.com/F4yy9tY2)):

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -input_format yuyv422 -video_size 1280x720 -i /dev/video4 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 1280x720 -r 30 -g 60 -f mpegts udp://238.0.0.1:5000
```

*what really bothered me about this is I had waited 25s after firing up both client and server to get a picture with the above command.*

*Further, and **this is a major issue I have experienced so far**, I have a 5-7s delay on my stream - I understand that hd encoding may help and network propogation takes time, but on a small 5G network I should not have to wait 7s for a bad quality (almost 144p @ 5-10fps) video stream*

Diagnosing this issue on IRC, I was asked to provide the following:

- `ffmpeg -f v4l2 -list_formats all -i /dev/video4` [result](https://pastebin.com/GQWgEmNm)
- `v4l2-ctl --list-devices`

  ```
  pi@raspberrypi:~ $ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
  bcm2835-codec-decode (platform:bcm2835-codec):
      /dev/video10
      /dev/video11
      /dev/video12

  Intel(R) RealSense(TM) Depth Ca (usb-0000:01:00.0-2):
      /dev/video0
      /dev/video1
      /dev/video2
      /dev/video3
      /dev/video4
      /dev/video5
  ```
- `v4l2-ctl --list-formats`

  ```
  pi@raspberrypi:~ $ v4l2-ctl --list-formats
  ioctl: VIDIOC_ENUM_FMT
      Type: Video Capture

      [0]: 'Z16 ' (16-bit Depth)
      [1]: '' (00000050-0000-0010-8000-00aa003)
  ```
- `ffmpeg -encoders | grep h264` [full output](https://pastebin.com/yQ1V5Yug)

  ```
   V..... libx264              libx264 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 (codec h264)
   V..... libx264rgb           libx264 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 RGB (codec h264)
   V..... h264_omx             OpenMAX IL H.264 video encoder (codec h264)
   V..... h264_v4l2m2m         V4L2 mem2mem H.264 encoder wrapper (codec h264)
  ```

  V..... h264_vaapi           H.264/AVC (VAAPI) (codec h264)
- `ffmpeg -encoders | grep h264` [full output](https://pastebin.com/cBaPVk7N)

  ```
   VFS..D h264                 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10
   V..... h264_v4l2m2m         V4L2 mem2mem H.264 decoder wrapper (codec h264)
   V..... h264_mmal            h264 (mmal) (codec h264)
  ```

What is preventing me from getting a good quality 720p image over the network, and what causes this 5-7s delay (even after adding -g 60 as mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1518680/stream-intel-realsense-camera-feed-to-networking-using-raspberry-pi-4-with-ffmpe?noredirect=1#comment2299353_1518680))